# What is the meaning of the comparision operators for strings?

Tags: c++, string

I am giving a class in C++, so our topic was about operator overloading, from the text book that I am using "C++ How to program for Deitel" and there is this example, where he compares 2 strings which logically doesn't make any sense.

My question is in the following example. How come s2 is smaller then s1 in comparison using alphabool?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s1{ "happy" };
    string s2{ " birthday" };
    string s3; // creates an empty string

    // test overloaded equality and relational operators
    cout << "s1 is \"" << s1 << "\"; s2 is \"" << s2
        << "\"; s3 is \"" << s3 << '\"'
        << "\n\nThe results of comparing s2 and s1:" 
        << "\ns2 == s1 yields " << (s2 == s1)
        << "\ns2 != s1 yields " << (s2 != s1)
        << "\ns2 >  s1 yields " << (s2 > s1)
        << "\ns2 <  s1 yields " << (s2 < s1)
        << "\ns2 >= s1 yields " << (s2 >= s1)
        << "\ns2 <= s1 yields " << (s2 <= s1)
        <<"Size of string s1 is:"<<s1.length()
        <<"Size if string s2 is:"<<s2.length();

}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare

Comment: A white space is a character as well, you know

Comment: Your question title is misleading, the question is not at all about operator overloading but it's about string comparison.

Comment: you are right, but the chapter in the text book mentioned above was about operator overloading, and this was used as an example overther

Comment: @DiaAbdulkarim people here don't care about the title of the chapter of the books you have read but only about the content of the question.

Comment: yeah Okay, although my question was misleading as you assume, I  got a sufficient answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space character at the beginning of `s2` comes before the `h` at the beginning of `s1` in the ASCII chart, so `s2` gets sorted first. Fortunately, if that isn't the behavior you want, the standard library includes ways of using different sorting algorithms. For example, some versions of `std::lexicographical_compare` take a parameter of type `Compare` that can be any function that takes two elements of the same type and returns `true` if and only if the two elements are in the desired order. (You can also use a "function-like object", i.e., a class that implements a `operator()` that takes two elements and returns a `bool`). Similarly, containers like `std::set` and `std::map` that keep their elements in sorted order take a template type argument `Compare` that can be used to sort their elements however you like.

Now, that sounds like a lot of work compared to just doing `s1 < s2`, huh? Well, if you like, you can create your own string class with its own `operator<` implemented however you like. One way to do that is like this:

```
class myString: public std::string
{
    // ...
};

bool operator<(const myString &ms1, const myString &ms2)
{
    return std::lexicographical_compare(ms1.begin(), ms1.end(), ms2.begin(), ms2.end(), customComparison);
}
```

Now, you do have to be a bit careful depending on how you do this - in this case, you need to be careful not to hand `myString` objects to something that's expecting an `std::string`, since it would try to sort them like `std::string` objects instead - but there are various techniques for mitigating that if you decide it's something you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

What is being used right there is [Lexicographical Comparison](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare). To explain it simply, when comparing two string value this way, the one word that would first appear in a dictionnary is the one that will be considered "little than" the second. Basically, each characters of the two string values are compared one by one until the ASCII code of one has a lower value than the one of the other.

In your particular case, the space at the start of your " birthday" string has a lower ASCII value than the one of the h of your "happy" string. So it is sorted first.

Answer (score 0):

Although `string` is intended for text and all text has an encoding, the comparison operators treat a string as a sequence of bytes—numeric values. So, no matter how the bytes go into the string and, if text, which encoding is used, the comparison is over numeric sequences, lexicographically. This means an element by element comparison up until the first difference or the end of one or both of the sequences.

[C++ String class](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

> Note that this class handles bytes independently of the encoding used: If used to handle sequences of multi-byte or variable-length characters (such as UTF-8), all members of this class (such as length or size), as well as its iterators, will still operate in terms of bytes (not actual encoded characters).